# ShutdownNow from executorService interface isn't shutting down task in process

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, shutdown

I have used shutdownNow to shut the processes immediately after first process gives some output from invokeAny method. But In output I can see even after calling shutDownNow(), processes are in flow of completion and complete their work and only then shutting down.
Code:

```
int numberOfRecordsInsertedSuccessfully = 0;
    List<String> userRecordList = readFile(
            "C:\\Users\\sonar\\git\\MultiThreading-Cocurrency\\JavaSEConcurrencyAPIStudyProject\\src\\main\\java\\Resources\\ExecutorServiceUserFile.txt");
    // ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();  //Thread pool of single thread.
    // ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3); //Thread pool size is 3 here
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

    List<Callable<Integer>> listOfCallable= new ArrayList<>();
    userRecordList.forEach(x -> listOfCallable.add(new UserProcessor(x, userDao)));

    try {
        Integer future = executorService.invokeAny(listOfCallable);
        System.out.println(future);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(executorService.shutdownNow());
    System.out.println("ExecutorService is shutting down " + executorService.isShutdown()); //After getting first future result this statement will be executed.
    System.out.println("ExecutorService is Terminated " + executorService.isTerminated());
```

Output on console is:
[image]

For More Details regarding code please refer above git link with

class: ExecutorServiceThreeTypesOfShutDownMethodMainClass

package: com.Concurrency.JavaSEConcurrencyAPIStudyProject.HighLevelApis.ExecutorServiceInterface

Project to use: JavaSEConcurrencyAPIStudyProject

git Link: [Git link for project for more details](https://github.com/priyankawagh9/MultiThreading-Cocurrency.git)

Please help, Why this is happening? how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Javadoc for that method says the following:

There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

So if your tasks do not check interrupted flag and catch and ignore `InterruptedException` then `shutdownNow()` will not be able to stop them

Comment: @PriyankaWagh - The solution is to change your task code so that it *does* check for interrupts and it *does* handle `InterruptedException` correctly.  (And that includes any 3rd-party libraries that your task code is calling.)

Comment: @Ivan Thanks alot. I hope may be the point you share is valid but in that case I don't find any sense to use ShutdownNow() instead of Shutdown() to immediately stop the process.

Comment: @Stephen C Can you please suggest what code changes are required for the code? Bcos I am new in multhithreading and concurrency and want to know it.

Comment: Start by reading this:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: (The code changes are not required in the code that you have shown us ... so you are going to have to work it out for yourself.  After reading the tutorial.)